# How to compare a String with Date?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to take a file in specified folder, pick out the date-part of the filename and compare this with the current date. If the date in the filename is smaller than the current date the file should be deleted.

The date is given in the filename like dd.mm.yy

```vb
Public Sub DeleteOldFiles()

    Dim FolderOld, CheckDate, ValFile As String
    
    FolderOld = "O:\temp\"

    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FS.GetFolder(FolderOld)
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        CheckDate = File.Name
        ValFile = Mid(DateiName, InStr(CheckDate, "valid until ") + 12) 'cut of everything before the date
        ValFile = Left(ValFile, 8) 'cut everything behind the date
  
        If ValFile < Format(Date(), "dd.mm.yy") Then
            Kill FolderOld & CheckDate
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

My code works if it only concerns the day-part of the date. For instance, today is August 28th.

If the filename contains 28.08.19, it is valid and is not deleted, as expected.

If the filename contains 26.08.19, it isn't valid and is deleted, as expected.

But if the filename contains 26.09.19, it is deleted although still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare the dates like this:

```
If Format(ValFile ,"yyyy-mm-dd") <= Format(Date(),"yyyy-mm-dd") Then......etc.
```